# Using the chess.js module in Nuxt

Tags: npm, vuejs2, nuxt.js, chess

I am trying to use the [chess.js](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js) module in a Nuxt app but the installation instructions don't seem to work for Nuxt.

```js
const { Chess } = require('chess.js')
const chess = new Chess()
```

The above code gives me `Chess is not a constructor`

Is there any way to convert the chess.js module to work with Nuxt? Could I scoop out its guts from the chess.js script in their repo and make it into a plugin? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Btw, your project is Vue2 because Nuxt is not available with Vue3 as of today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `import` syntax and to call `new Chess()` in `mounted()`.